# Matemáticas o Matemática

Tags: uso-de-palabras, plurales, matemáticas, ciencia

If I am trying to say:

> Mathematics is a very interesting subject

Which of these would be:

> Matemáticas son muy interesantes
>
> Matemáticas es muy interesante
>
> Matemática es muy interesante

I have found conflicting answers online as to this.

Comment: Usually without article sounds very bad.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the DRAE, you can use either [Matemática](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=matem%C3%A1tica) or Matemáticas.

I would use your sentence in Spanish as:

> Las Matemáticas son muy interesantes.

Comment: I am agree with this comment

Comment: Gidrek, its: I agree. I was making this mistake for very long time ;)

Comment: @DavidSánchez "it is" or "it's" ; )

Answer (score 4):

Como bien [dice Jose María](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13654/1674), ambas opciones son válidas. Sin embargo, el propio Diccionario de la RAE explicita que la forma plural es más usada:

> **[matemática](http://dle.rae.es/matem%C3%A1tica)**
>
> (Del lat. mathematĭca, y este del gr. τὰ μαθηματικά, der. de μάθημα,
>   conocimiento).
>
> 1. f. Ciencia deductiva que estudia las propiedades de los entes abstractos, como números, figuras geométricas o símbolos, y sus
>      relaciones. **U. m. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.**

Esto es, "utilizado más en plural con el mismo significado que en singular".

La Wikipedia incide en este hecho en la sección de Etimología de su [artículo "Matemáticas"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matem%C3%A1ticas#Etimolog.C3.ADa):

> La forma más usada es el plural matemáticas, que tiene el mismo
>   significado que el singular y viene de la forma latina *mathematica*
>   (Cicerón), basada en el plural en griego *τα μαθηματικά* (*ta
>   mathēmatiká*), usada por Aristóteles y que significa, a grandes
>   rasgos, «todas las cosas matemáticas»

---

Respecto las frases que sugieres, en todas ellas debes añadir el artículo:

> *Las* Matemáticas ...

Comment: La nota del DRAE significa "Usado **más** en plural [...]", lo que está de acuerdo con la cita de Wikipedia.

Comment: @Gorpik ya decía yo que este "m." debía querer decir algo importante... : ) Muchas gracias, edito la respuesta para destacar este punto.